# Appium Driver selects the wrong value in Android Spinner

Tags: android-spinner, appium-android

The spinner has values(1 to 10).
Code is set to select 2, but 1 is selected.

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "quantity_spinner")
private AndroidElement spinnerQuantity;

public void setQuantity(String val){
    spinnerQuantity.click();
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+val+"']").click();
}

//function call
setQuantity('2');
```

Appium Version 1.4.1 on Samsung 7

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value as string and not character. In your code it should be "2" and not '2'. Also update Appium to latest stable version